# LDAP based solution for office 365

Tags: java, authorization, office365

The current system is using a LDAP based solution for authorizing user roles which works for 2003-2007 Microsoft Exchange servers but system is failing for Office365 since its cloud based.

Can you suggest how i can achieve LDAP based solution in office 365?

Answer (score 2):

You won't be able to implement anything in office365, it is a proprietary (closed) system that has it's own login and management system.